# Java2D & Image creation

Tags: java, image, drawing, resize, awt

I want to dynamically create some image from Java and save it to a file.
As I read in various tutorials, I need to use BufferedImage.

But, the BufferedImage constructor requires that the height and width as parameters. But I don't know the final size of my image. How should I create an image with size unknown in advance?

There are two obvious strategies:

1. Create a very large image initially, say 10000x10000.
2. Gradually creating larger image, and copying the original to it. The drawback is that I need to check the bounds before each time I want to add something.

How do you deal with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just run into space vs time issue here. I would be going for the first strategy of creating a very large image 10000x10000, the simple reason being the second approach you say involves mountains of matrix copies which you would want to avoid at any cost.

Moreover, with a good knowledge of the image size, you can further optimize that value of 10000 x 10000 to something like 1000x1000 initially. If the image seems to exceed this, double it like 2000 x 2000 and copy the old one to the new one and keep doing this as your image expands.. This is more of a proven strategy that is used in the famous `java.util.ArrayList`

By this way, you are indirectly bridging the time vs space trade-off. And yes, you will have to calculate the bounds everytime but that does not look a big task to me, it can be done in O(1) time.

Answer (score 0):

Of course we don't know the specifics of your problem but a simple approach could be like this: You build some kind of model of your image: Which shape goes where and how large is it. From that you should be able to calculate the dimensions of the total image.